# The connectivity of a simple graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

> Let $G = \langle V, E \rangle$ be a simple graph such that $|V| = 7$ and $|E| = 16$.
>
>  Denote the number of G's components by $\alpha$. Is it necessary that $\alpha = 1$?

I think that the statement is indeed true - by observing the complete graph $K_{7}$ which represents the most simple scenario (.i.e G is $K_{7}$), it seems intuitively that I could find a path between any two vertices on the complete graph after "removing" the five edges too. However, my struggle is in formalizing it\find the cases which I need to observe between.

Obviously that one case is when there exists some $v \in V$ which satisfies $deg(v) = 6$. Otherwise, I claimed that each vertex is at least of degree 1 and since $|V|$ is odd, by the Handshaking lemma we get that there is some $u\in V$ s.t $deg(v) \in$ {$2, 4$}. But still, I don't see how it leads into a contradiction.

I'd like for some clarification/ideas, thanks.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is disconnected.  Then $V$ can be partitioned into two nonempty node sets $V_1$ and $V_2$, with cardinalities $n_1$ and $n_2$ and no edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$.  So $n_1+n_2=|V|=7$ and $\binom{n_1}{2}+\binom{n_2}{2} \ge |E| = 16$.

Comment: This is so clean, what was your intuition to use this inequality?

Comment: If you suspect connected, then a natural approach is contradiction.  Then it's just a matter of giving names to the node counts and expressing the given information in terms of those variables.

Comment: The complement graph has $21 - 6 = 5$ edges, so it cannot be connected, but the complement of any disconnected graph is connected because it contains a complete bipartite graph.